# R chartSeries add extra chart with points

Tags: r, charts, quantmod, candlestick-chart

I have a question regarding `chartSeries` and the `addTA` / `points.default` functions in `R`. I am trying to add an extra chart below the `chartSeries`-plot with points in different colours (colouring is taken from a function and working with `points.default`), but  unfortunately I'm unable to add these points with `addTA`. I am able to add a line to the existing charts (both not what i am looking for). The `points.default` function simply add those points into the chartSeries, which is not what i am looking for. I am looking for a simple straight line of points i can coloring differently with my `color_fct` and which is added below my `chartSeries`. I appreciate any help and thank you in advance!

Example Code:

```
getSymbols("YHOO")
data <- YHOO
chartSeries(data, type = c("auto", "candlesticks", "matchsticks","bars","line"))
hero<-rep(1,length(data$Close))
c(data, xts(hero))
#addTA provides me with a straight line and the coloring fct is not working
plot(addTA(data$hero,pch = 15,cex = 1.5, on = 2, col = color_fct))
#points.default provides me with perfect coloring, but the points are plotted in the middle of the chart
help<- rep(1, length(data$Close))
points.default(x=(1:length(data$High)),y=help+1, col= color_fct,pch = 15,cex = 1.5)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are open to using the newer `chart_Series` instead of `chartSeries`:

```
x_ti <- xts(rnorm(NROW(data)), order.by = index(data))
x_ti2 <- xts(rep(1, NROW(data)), order.by = index(data))
x_ti2[1, ] <- 0.5 # work around to get an xts object with all the same values (of 1) to plot if points are not visible on the subplot

chart_Series(data["2017"])
add_TA(x_ti, col = "purple", pch = 15, type = 'p', cex = .7)
# plot straight line in subplot:
add_TA(x_ti2, col = "orange", pch = 9, type = 'p', cex = .7)
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, I found a bug. I am using shiny with a slider. The slider works perfectly on the `chart_Series`, but has a problem with the straight line. Everytime i zoom it, it fixes the values on the left side. If I zoom to the right side, the values from the left side remain , while `chart_Series` zooms in on the right side. Is there an option such that the `zoom_chart` zooms into your answer as well?

Comment: As far as i understood your Code, it adds a seperate Chart, independent of the chart_Series. Is this a right assumption? Is there a way to connect both charts?

Comment: You can chart all items together with this when using Shiny:  `chart_Series(data["2017"], TA = 'add_TA(x_ti, col = "purple", pch = 15, type = "p", cex = .7);
             add_TA(x_ti2, col = "orange", pch = 9, type = "p", cex = .7)')`

Comment: Also, your 'bug' with shiny is really another question.  You should make another question with reproducible shiny code if you expect an answer.

Comment: Ah ok, sorry and thank you for your advise. I am still new to stackoverflow and don't know the rules fully yet. I'll open a new post with shiny code as well. Your Input really helped me and my understanding of the code, thank you!

Comment: Is it possible to plot these points directly onto the main chart, for example if the main chart were a line graph?

Comment: @fraxture  using `on = 1` in the  `add_TA` call should draw on the main plot